# Pinterest redirect URI

Tags: api, redirect, uri, http-redirect, pinterest

I am trying to pull the data with Pinterest API. I need to provide the redirect uri, but I can't find any guidance on how to do so. Where can I get a valid redirect URI from the Pinterest App profile?
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinterest has shutdown their API V1 and they do not approve APPs for their new API V2.
They are very strict with their new API and you have to go through a very deep approval process and at the end you mostly get denied....